# Struggling to convert an Object to have keys within one of the sub objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm struggling to convert this file so that the clientID is the key on the Object within 'things'. I want to flatten the array and then have keys for each Object within an outer Object.

```
{
 "id": "575802",
 "things": [{
         "clientId": "123456",
         "val": "file1"
     },
     {
         "clientId": "1234",
         "val": "file2"
     }
 ]
}
```

The above I want to be

```
{  
"id":"575802",
"things":{  
   "123456":{  
      "val":"file1"
   },
   "1234":{  
      "val":"file2"
   }
}
}
```

I've tried using various ways of using Object.entries but I can't find something specific for the purpose of getting an ID out to be the key

Comment: What have you tried so far. Can you post some code so we have an idea of the direction you are heading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` on `things` array

```js
const obj = {
 "id": "575802",
 "things": [{
         "clientId": "123456",
         "val": "file1"
     },
     {
         "clientId": "1234",
         "val": "file2"
     }
 ]
}
obj.things = obj.things.reduce((ac,{clientId,...rest}) => (ac[clientId] = rest, ac), {})
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to create the `things` key in the required object. In `reduce` callback function return an object

```js
let data = {
  "id": "575802",
  "things": [{
      "clientId": "123456",
      "val": "file1"
    },
    {
      "clientId": "1234",
      "val": "file2"
    }
  ]
}

let newData = {
  id: data.id,
  things: data.things.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    acc[curr.clientId] = {
      val: curr.val
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
};

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an ideal solution (based on how dynamic you need the solution to be).

But here is the fastest solution I came up with.

```
const data = {
  id: '575802',
  things: [{
    clientId: '123456',
    val: 'file1'
  },
    {
      clientId: '1234',
      val: 'file2'
    }
  ]
};

const resultObj = {};
resultObj['id'] = data['id'];
resultObj['things'] = {};
const things = data['things'];
for (const thing of things) {
  const clientId = thing['clientId'];
  resultObj['things'][clientId] = {val: thing['val']};
}

console.log(resultObj);
```

All I am doing here is iterating over the 'things' property and flattening it into the desired object.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, much appreciated!